# Prove that $\arcsin\bigl(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\bigr)=2\arctan t$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Prove that$$\arcsin\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)=2\arctan t.$$

I found a list of inverse functions trig.

[image]

But, in above list every rules have square root. At first the problem was related to
$$\sin(\arctan x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

But, it has square root in denominator. So, I got confused.

Comment: To prove any of these rules, draw a right triangle and label the appropriate sides with the numerator and denominator of those fractions.

Comment: Not true for $t=\sqrt{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try evaluating $\sin(2\tan^{-1}(t)) = 2\sin(\tan^{-1}(t))\cos(\tan^{-1}(t))$

Answer (score 0):

This method assumes knowledge of calculus:

Define $f(t) = \arcsin\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)-2\arctan(t).$ Differentiating it, we get $f'(t)= 0$. Since $f(0) = 0$, the identity follows.

Method 2:$$\tan(2\arctan(t)) = \frac{2\tan(\arctan(t))}{1-(\tan(\arctan(t)))^2}=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}.$$
Using Pythagorean theorem, one could obtain $\tan\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)\right) = \frac{2t}{1-t^2}$.

Comment: I don't think that your answer is helpful. Cause, you didn't declare any value with x in function (on RHS). So, differentiation of constant is forever 0. So, your answer is unhelpful. Although, I am not downvoting...

Comment: @Istiak i think kyle meant to write $f(t)$ and not $f(x)$.

Comment: @CSquared hmm! He had made changes but, maybe forgot to change another one.